# Hindi Content are not displaying through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display some Hindi words using JQuery because these are the common content which should be display on each page of the web site. 
Note - This is a static website only. Using HTML and JQuery/javascript.

My JS file is below -
 include.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var text="<div class='header-main'>मुख्य पृष्ठ कुछ हिंदी के शब्द </div>";                  

$(".header__fixed").html(text);                        
});
```

my html file is -
index.html

```
<body>
 <header class="header header__fixed">

</header>
</body>
```

But it is displaying something like -

????????? in the header div.
Please help me to solve this problem.

[image]

Here is the screen shot of the error when i am saving the .js file.
Please help me to get out this problem.
I already included the  in my html file.

Comment: Its working for me https://jsfiddle.net/zfb37pfp/

Comment: Works for me on jsfiddle. Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/7jrrqbxb/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058662/language-format-issue-meta-tag

Comment: but not working when i am using in my web site.. One thing i need to add, when i am saving the js file it prompting me some unicode character error and file not saving the hindi character but saving  character in this '????' format.

Comment: Check your character set in your html. For unicode support, it be better to use UTF-8 like:
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: it is showing correctly when i am using it in the HTML directly. But it is not showing when i am using it through JQuery.

i added <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
but not working...

Comment: Is there any way to set UTF-8 through JQuery which i am using.
?Whenever  i am trying to save the .js file it is showing some UNICODE  error and replacing the HIndi words to '???????' formats....
Is there any way to change character set in js file

Answer (score 1):

Add `<meta charset="utf-8">` to the `<head>` of your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

hi first off all you need to add this two things in to html tag **encoding="UTF-8" charset="UTF-8"** like..

```html
<html encoding="UTF-8" charset="UTF-8">
```

and yes the second is the main thing that you need to save this html with **Encoding in UTF-8** option this will make hindi characters available try this by creating example locally this will run

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer of my problem... It is so simple.. Just save the file with Unicode character set. I am using dreamweaver and have changes the character type by saving as file.

```html
<html encoding="UTF-8" charset="UTF-8">
```